# Pass access token from Auth0 to winsdkfb

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, uwp, auth0

In UWP, I've logged in to Facebook using Auth0 and have an access token.`id_token`.
Now, I want to use winsdkfb to do other operations likes posting.
I've tried to set the access token in winsdkfb as:

```
var sess = FBSession.ActiveSession;
sess.AccessTokenData = new FBAccessTokenData(user.IdToken, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddHours(10)));
//user is what returns from auth0 login.
```

This does not still work as the `session.LoggedIn` is false and I don't want to log in again with winsdkfb with `sess.LoginAsync()`

How do I use winsdkfb after loggin in with Auth0.

Comment: winsdkfb seems not exposed an API to use the 'custom' `access_token`. So this is not a feasible scenario. Please try using  HttpClient to call the fb API.

Answer (score 1):

Auth0 access token is access token for Auth0 API, not any other (FB in this case). To use FB API you need to obtain FB access token.

Never done that on my own, by Auth0 for sure has them as it needs them to authenticate against given provider.

Auth0 documentation describes such scenario:

- https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/calling-an-external-idp-api
- https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/idp